# Check the change of API with observable and update data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable

I have a web service that provide information about the (last) song that is currently playing on a radio.

How can my observable update the data from my http request by itself?

My provider:

```
  load() : Observable<{}> {
    return this.http.get(this.URL).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

My component:

```
this.radio.load().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

What I want, basically is "data" to be updated every time the web service response change!  How can I do that?

Comment: Does that mean that you want to make a call to this web service every X amount of time?

Comment: Yes, every time the data change, except I don't have a way to know when the song has ended, so i don't know when the data change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this: In your component, call `load()` every 10 seconds, and check whether the data has changed (I believe that you'd want to save a property on your component which holds the most recent data).

Here's how to do it with RxJS:

```
IntervalObservable.create(10 * 1000 /* 10 seconds */)
    .takeWhile(() => this.alive) // only fires when component is alive
    .subscribe(() => {
        .radio.load()
        .subscribe(data => {
            /* ...check if data has changed... */
            console.log(data);
        });
});
```

Regarding `this.alive` - this is merely just a property on your component that needs to be set to false when the component is destroyed (i.e. upon calling `ngOnDestroy`), and needs to be set to true when the component is initialized (probably on `ngOnInit`).

(you could, of course, use the more traditional `setInterval` and `clearInterval` way of doing the same thing.)